# Rails + JS + Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I'm making simple clone of game where is Waldo (Wally) with Rails + JS + Ajax. The idea is: player becomes 3 images and has to check where 3 characters (Waldo,Wilma,Wizard) are. After 3. image shows up field to submit name and after submit show high score list.

So far, i have code the mechanism for time (JS variable with setInterval), points (JS + AJAX + rails controller) but i can't code the action for submit name, points and time to model.

My view file:

```
<%= form_tag('/check/highscore',  method: :post, format: :js, remote: true ) do %> 
    <%= text_field_tag 'name', 'enter your name' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
  <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $.ajax({
 url: "<%= highscore_check_index_path %>",
 type: "POST",
 format: "js",
 dataType: "script",
 data: { username: $(this).username, score: guessd, time: time  }, 
 success: function(data) {
 $('send_highscore').append('data.username')    
 window.waldo.HS()
},
});
};
```

my controller file:

```
def highscore
 @username = params[:name] 
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :layout => false } 
  format.html
 end
end
def highscore2
 record = Highscore.new 
 record.username = params[:username]
 record.score = params[:score] 
 record.time = params[:time]
 record.save 
end
```

my highscore.js.erb

```
console.log("<%=j @username %>");

window.waldo.HS = function(username) {
 $.ajax({
  url: "<%= highscore2_check_index_path %>",
  type: "POST",
  format: "js",
  data: { username: name, score: guessd, time: time  }, 
  success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
 $('send_highscore').append('data.username')    
}
});
});
```

I know, my oode is very bad quality, but i try to learn it now. Problem is that the highscore.js.erb is not executed although i see it in firebug rendered as a js script file. 
The idea of highscore.js.erb is to mix ruby and js variables and together sent do highscore2 action in check controller and save to db.

Comment: try wrapping it in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I've tried but it didn't change anything.
I can't invoke the function window.waldo.HS() in console.

Comment: are you getting any errors?. If any do share...Meanwhile,have you enabled `turbolinks`?

Answer (score 0):

### js.erb is a bad way to learn.

Ruby on Rails can be used as a kind of poor mans Single Page Architecture by using `remote: true` and returning JS.erb responses. But all it really does it gives you enough rope to hang yourself.

Its a really bad way to learn ajax as it leads to poor code organisation and a very non RESTful application as it leads to a focus on procedures instead of resources.

I instead encourage you to try to learn ajax without mixing ERB and JS. Mixing server side and client side logic just makes everything much more complicated as you have to keep track of what is happening where.

Instead you might want to focus on setting up reusable javascript functions in `app/assets/javascripts` and fetching JSON data instead of javascript procedures.

This will teach you not only to do ajax in Rails but also how to do it with external API's and teach you valuable lessons about how to structure and organise code.

### So lets start looking at how to refactor:

Highscores should be a resource.

Lets start by setting up the routes:

```
resources :highscores, only: [:create, :index, :show]
```

And the controller:

```
class HighscoresController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def create
    @highscore = Highscore.create(highscore_params)
    respond_with @highscore
  end

  def index
    @highscores = Highscore.order(score: :desc).all
    respond_with @highscores
  end

  def show
    @highscore = Highscore.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @highscore
  end

  private
    def highscore_params
      params.require(:highscore).permit(:username, :time, :score)
    end
end
```

[Responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) is a pretty awesome tool that makes it so that we don't have to do a bunch of boilerplate code when it comes to returning responses. Our create method will return `200 OK` if it was successful and `422 BAD ENTITY` or some other "bad" response code if it failed.

### Some javascript scaffolding

Lets set up a little bit of scaffolding so that we can hook our javascript up to a specific controller and action without using inline script tags.

Open up `layouts/application.html.erb` and replace the `<body>` tag:

```
<%= content_tag :body, data: { action: action_name, controller: controller_name } do %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

Then add this little piece to `applicaiton.js`:

```
// Triggers events based on the current controller and action.
// Example:
// given the controller UsersController and the action index
// users:loaded
// users.index:loaded
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
  var data = $('body').data();
  $(this).trigger(data.controller + ":loaded")
         .trigger(data.controller + "." + data.action + ":loaded");
});
```

### Where is that ajax y'all was talkin' bout?

Lets say we have a list of highscores that we want to update either at regular intervals (polling) or when the user submits a highscore.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/highscores.js
function getHighscores(){
  var $self = $('.highscores-list');
  return $.getJSON('/highscores').done(function(highscores){
    var elements = $.map(highscores, function(h){
      return $('<li>').text([h.username, h.score].join(', '));
    });
    $self.empty().append(elements);
  });
};

$(document).on('games:loaded highscores:loaded', function(){
  // refresh highscores every 5 seconds
  (function refresh(){
    getHighscores().done(function(){
      window.setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
    });
  }());
});
```

That last part is a bit hairy - its a recursive function that sets a new timer when the ajax call has completed. The reason we use this and not `setInterval` is that `setInterval` does not care if the previous call was completed or not.

### Creating Highscores.

First lets russle up a form:

```
<%# app/views/highscores/_form.html.erb %>
<%= form_for(local_assigns[:highscore] || Highscore.new), class: 'highscore-form' do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :score %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :time %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And then lets spiff it up with some ajax goodness:

```
$(document).on('games:loaded highscores:loaded', function(){
  $('#new_highscore').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax(this.action, {
      data: {
        highscore: {
          username: this.elements["highscore[username]"].value,
          time: this.elements["highscore[time]"].value,
          score: this.elements["highscore[score]"].value
        }
      },
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function(data, status, jqXHR){
      getHighscores();
      // todo notify user
    });
    return false; // prevent form from being submitted normally
  });
});
```

Comment: Full example is available here https://github.com/maxcal/waldo. Note that this uses global functions for brevity - i'll leave it up to you to modularize it.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I'm learning RoR on myself. So far it's been pretty simple for my, but the appropriate way to use JS+AJAX+RoR is not obvious to me. 
Your post made it a bit simpler for me, but today I'm to tired to crack it down, I'll deal with it seariously tomorrow ;). 
Do you know a good book or resource where could I read something more about that topic?

Comment: Not really sorry, I didn't really have a book when I was learning and learned from reading a lot of blog posts and watching talks by John Resig and Douglas Crockford.

Comment: Hi, today i've time and force to consider hot it shoulds work and I almoust understand it. But I don't get how the form_for could get the time and score values that I saved as javascript variables, for example time `script`:
    `$(document).ready(function(){`
      `time = 0;`
      `window.timer();`  
    `});`

    `window.timer = function(){`
     `time  ++;`
     `timerVar =  window.setTimeout(window.timer, 1000);`
    `};`

Comment: Just change the values of the form inputs. For example `$("#highscore_score").val(500)`.